# How can I access the auth_mellon nameId property in my javascript application

Tags: saml-2.0

I have implemented mod_auth_mellon in my apache httpd 2.4 webserver.  I configured Mellon to authenticate when I try to access my oracle JET application.

So far all is good, when I go to http://example.com, I am redirected to my sso login page and after entering my credentials I am sent back to https://example.com.

My problem is that once I return to my application at https://example.com, I need to be able to access the Mellon-nameid attribute so I can retrieve user privilleges from a database talbe based on email address.

According to all the docs I have read, mod_auth_mellon stores the mellonUser attribute in the apache environment, and/or the response headers.
Also according to what I have read, there is no way in my JET application to access the apache environment variables, and so far I haven't found a way to examine the response headers to get the mellonUser from there either.

Is there an alternate way to access the MellonUser attribute? Can it be stored in teh Mellon cookie, or maybe put on the url as a query parameter?

Also any methods for accessing the headers would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting here, even though it's an old thread.

So when you use Apache Mellon, you can supply the nameID in a header value.  If you are using apache as a proxy, (I.E you successfully authenticated, now go through the proxy), the web server can access the nameID as an attribute.  You can also pass whatever other SAML attributes you want (Assuming you already know how to do this, i'll leave this part out).

Now the problem is, that header value is something the web app (Backend) sees BEHIND the proxy.  Javascript is ran client side, in the user's actual browser.  So in this scenario it would not be able to see this value unless you tell the backend to send it forward.

As an example, if you setup Apache SAML and then have it proxy to a PHP app, and you have a page that simply dumps the headers:

```
<?php

foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}

?>
```

OR:

```
<?php
   var_dump($_SERVER);
?>
```

VIOLA, you can see the nameid and whatever other attributes!  However, go to your  web console, and poke around, or check out your headers... these will be different because you are getting headers from pre-proxy, while the webapp gets headers from the post-proxy.

So what can you do?  In my php example, since PHP will parse first, you can grab the variable from the backend, and echo it into a script that will be ran after this is all done.

```
<script>
   username = "<?php echo $YourHeaderNameID; ?>";
</script>
```

However, there is some danger to this as well.  Client side Javascript and be easily modified.  So if your username "johnsmith", and you wanted to change the website username to "joeschmoe", that would be trivial.  You should probably have the backend provide whatever user information you require, and then use javascript to style, rearrange, do whatever with.